# Need to extract string from within a random size string

Tags: javascript, selenium-ide

Having an issue with strings.  I have a long string like this:

```
"Other title of some text here name of file Date: 01/01/2011 Picture ID: UYT-2011-01 Company My company"
```

What I need to do is extract just the picture id , the `UYT-2011-01` part.  The text before and after is not a set size, could be an entire paragraph, the text after can be any length, and in fact the Picture ID itself could be anywhere from 15-20 characters long.

For my purposes, I want to extract the 15 characters in the string after the `Picture ID:`.

I am using Selenium IDE, so it would need to be a javascript or regexp method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your picture IDs don’t have spaces in them, and will always have a space after them, this regex solution should work in JavaScript:

```
var longString = "Other title of some text here name of file Date: 01/01/2011 Picture ID: UYT-2011-01 Company My company";

longString.match(/Picture ID: ([^ ]*)/);

// Returns ["Picture ID: UYT-2011-01", "UYT-2011-01"]

longString.match(/Picture ID: ([^ ]*)/)[1];

// Returns "UYT-2011-01"
```

Matching like this means that the picture ID can be any length, as long as it is delimited by space characters.

Answer (score 0):

Should should get you going.

```
var str = "Other title of some text here name of file Date: 01/01/2011 Picture ID: UYT-2011-01 Company My company";

var searchStart = "Picture ID:";
var start = str.indexOf(searchStart);
var end = str.indexOf("Company");
var part = str.substring(start, end);

//also part.replace(searchStart, "");

console.log(part);
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that where "Company" is not definitive, it could be anything there, that's just one example.